# Define data annotation attributes in one place but use in several view models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have multiple related ViewModels:

- ChangePasswordViewModel
- ResetPasswordViewModel
- RegisterViewModel

that each include multiple annotation attributes for the password property.

I would like to be able to define these attributes only once.

I tried using a MetadataType attribute to associate each ViewModel with a class that would include all of the associated attributes but since this includes properties that may not be in the individual View Models, I get an error message.

Comment: Have you considered using a base type like `PasswordBaseViewModel` or some such?

Answer (score 1):

Use inheritance:

```
public class BasePasswordViewModel
{
     [Required]
     public string Password { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class ChangePasswordViewModel: BasePasswordViewModel { //... }

public class ResetPasswordViewModel : BasePasswordViewModel { //... }

public class RegisterViewModel: BasePasswordViewModel { //... }
```

All of your "shared" properties can go in `BasePasswordViewModel` and anything that is specific to `ChangePasswordViewModel`, `ResetPasswordViewModel`, `RegisterViewModel` can go in there.